# Vim running slow with LaTeX files

Tags: performance, vim, latex, pathogen, supertab

I'm using Vim with a bunch of plugins (pathogen, ctags, snipmate, supertab, ...), and everything works fine for all kinds of file extensions.

However, when I'm try to edit .tex files it presents two problems which seem related. First, Vim starts to work really slow, and second, when I press "any letter + Tab", it tries to auto-complete with words previously written in the text.

One way which I tried to solve those issues, is by removing the supertab plugin from my bundle folder, but it's a not satisfactory solution.

Comment: Did you mean "when I press "any letter" + `<Tab>`"?

Comment: In C++ I tend to use `:set completeopt-=i` - not sure whether that helps for latex

Comment: I am also experiencing some slowness when editing latex files. Turning syntax highlighting for latex files seemed to work.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is due to the **relativenumber** option, when I turned it off the latex edit speed come back to normal.

Comment: For others experiencing the same problem, and sluggish UI in latex files, the problem may be `cursorline` is on. By toggling it `set nocursorline`, the UI becomes fully responsive. I don't have a reason why this happens only with latex documents.

Answer (score 2):

The following relativenumber, cursorline and MatchParen can slow vim down a lot, especially when dealing with large latex files. When I turn them off then vim becomes much more responsive when dealing with large latex files.

To turn off relative number, type the following in editor mode:

`:set nornu`

To turn off cursorline, type the following in editor mode:

`:set nocursorline`

To turn off MatchParen, type the following in editor mode:

`:NoMatchParen`

If you still want regular line numbering then you can have

`:set number`

For a more permanent solution, you can also set latex specific settings in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
" Latex specification
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex
    \ set nocursorline |
    \ set nornu |
    \ set number |
    \ let g:loaded_matchparen=1 |
```

The `\` and the `|` are there to allow you add the latex commands over multiple lines.

Comment: Oh wow, wow, this is aweful! `cursorline` had a huge impact for me. Any idea why this is happening. I feel like this really really shouldn't happen!

Answer (score 1):

The other two possible problems are the following being active

1. `cursorline`
2. `DoMatchParen`

So to make your LᴬTᴇX editing experience much better, you can do something like the following in your `~/.vimrc`

```
au FileType tex setlocal nocursorline
au FileType tex :NoMatchParen
```

After doing this my Vim is as fast with `.tex` files as it is with `.cpp` ones.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but, to anyone seeing this now, it is better to use the `ftplugin/` folder in your `.vim` directory to instruct Vim to enable certain options on a specific file type. Create a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` with the following options:

```
set nocursorline
set nornu
let g:loaded_matchparen=1
```

This makes Vim load these options only on TeX files (`*.tex` and related) without resorting to an `:autocommand` like [gloriphobia’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125073) does.

Comment: I think this should have been a comment on the mentioned answer, rather than an answer on its own (I also know that you don’t have enough rep to comment, sorry).

Comment: Thanks to your edit I can now comment everywhere hahaha). The author has not picked an accepted answer. Should I just comment on the question itself?

Comment: Great. :-) I’d say you put it below gloriphobia’s answer, although the same advice would apply to other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Folding** is another common source of slowdown. It is normally disabled by default, but perhaps you have enabled it. You can just disable it again:

```
" (1) if you use the builtin TeX support:
  " comment the line in your vimrc that looks like this:
  "let g:tex_fold_enabled = ...
  " OR, just to be sure, do:
  unlet! g:tex_fold_enabled

" (2) if you rather use VimTeX:
  " comment the line in your vimrc that looks like this:
  "let g:vimtex_fold_enabled = 1
  " OR, just to be sure, do:
  let g:vimtex_fold_enabled = 0
```

Note that folding must be enabled/disabled *before* TeX syntax is loaded in the buffer. Also, Vim option `'foldenable'` (toggled by the normal-mode command `zi`) does not actually clear folding, it just hides it but it’s still there).

**However,** if you don’t want to give up on folding altogether, I found a single bottleneck in the builtin TeX folding that was responsible for most of the slowdown in my case: the `document` environment. Simple test: typing stuff just before `\begin{document}` is reasonably fast, but typing right after it is amazingly laggy. I guess it happens because that environment commonly spans hundreds of lines.

If you use the builtin TeX folding, you can prevent the folding of just the `document` environment by disabling the `texDocZone` matchgroup¹. Anyway, why would you want to fold the toplevel contents?

```
" put this in your vimrc :
au FileType tex :syntax clear texDocZone
" OR put this in ~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim :
syntax clear texDocZone
```

Alternatively, if you have VimTeX, you can replace the builtin TeX folding with the VimTeX’ one. I find it generally better, and it carefully avoids folding the `document` environment.

```
" put this in your vimrc :
unlet! g:tex_fold_enabled  " just to be sure
let g:vimtex_fold_enabled = 1
```

VimTeX’ folding is nicely customizable, see `:help vimtex-folding`.

---

¹ As of version 121 (April 2022) of [the builtin TeX syntax](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/tex.vim).